# Popular TableView com dados vindos do derby apache

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc

Estou tentando popular tableview com dados do derby apache mais não estou conseguindo. Segue o código:

Classe TelaAgenda:

```
package view;

import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import controller.Main;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import model.Aluno;
import model.Agenda;
import model.DAO.AgendaDAO;
import model.DAO.AlunoDAO;

public class TelaAgenda extends Application {

    private static ListView<String> listView;
    private static TableView<Agenda> table;
    private static Button buttonNovo;
    private static Button buttonSalvar;
    private static TableColumn tableColuna1;
    private static TableColumn tableColuna2;
    private static TableColumn tableColuna3;
    private static TableColumn tableColuna4;
    private static TableColumn tableColuna5;
    private static TableColumn tableColuna6;
    private static Label labelreferencia;
    private static Label labeldescricao;
    private static TextField textFielddescricao;
    private static Label labelvalor;
    private static TextField textFieldvalor;

    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox0;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox1;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox2;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox3;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox4;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox5;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox6;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox7;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox8;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox9;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox10;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox11;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox12;
    private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox13;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // private String nome;
    // private String descricao;
    // private String valor;
    // private String diasaulas;
    // private String tiposaulas;

    private static AgendaDAO agendadao;
    private static Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
    private static Aluno aluno;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(vbox);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Agendamento");

        tableColuna1 = new TableColumn<>("Matricula");
        tableColuna1.setMinWidth(50);
        tableColuna1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Agenda, Integer>("matricula"));
        tableColuna1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColuna1.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Agenda, Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Agenda, Integer> event) {
                ((Agenda) event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                        .setMatricula(event.getNewValue());

            }

        });

        tableColuna2 = new TableColumn<>("Nome");
        tableColuna2.setMinWidth(200);
        tableColuna2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Agenda, String>("nome"));
        tableColuna2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColuna2.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Agenda, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Agenda, String> event) {
                ((Agenda) event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                        .setNome(event.getNewValue());

            }

        });

        tableColuna3 = new TableColumn<>("Descrição");
        tableColuna3.setMinWidth(200);
        tableColuna3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Agenda, String>("descricao"));
        tableColuna3.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColuna3.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Agenda, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Agenda, String> event) {
                ((Agenda) event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                        .setDescricao(event.getNewValue());

            }

        });

        tableColuna4 = new TableColumn<>("Valor");
        tableColuna4.setMinWidth(200);
        tableColuna4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Agenda, String>("valor"));
        tableColuna4.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColuna4.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Agenda, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Agenda, String> event) {
                ((Agenda) event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                        .setValor(event.getNewValue());

            }

        });

        tableColuna5 = new TableColumn<>("DiasAulas");
        tableColuna5.setMinWidth(200);
        tableColuna5.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Agenda, String>("diasaulas"));
        tableColuna5.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColuna5.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Agenda, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Agenda, String> event) {
                ((Agenda) event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                        .setDiasaulas(event.getNewValue());

            }

        });

        tableColuna6 = new TableColumn<>("TiposAulas");
        tableColuna6.setMinWidth(200);
        tableColuna6.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Agenda, String>("tiposaulas"));
        tableColuna6.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableColuna6.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Agenda, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Agenda, String> event) {
                ((Agenda) event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                        .setTiposaulas(event.getNewValue());

            }

        });

        table = new TableView<Agenda>();
        table.setItems(agenda.atualizarTabela());
        table.setPrefSize(740, 280);

        table.setEditable(true);

        table.getColumns().addAll(tableColuna1, tableColuna2, tableColuna3, tableColuna4, tableColuna5, tableColuna6);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);

        labelreferencia = new Label("Pressione Ctrl e clique sobre o dia da semana para marcar ou desmarcar");
        labelreferencia.setFont(new Font(16));
        labelreferencia.setPrefSize(530, 30);
        labelreferencia.setLayoutX(5);
        labelreferencia.setLayoutY(523);

        labeldescricao = new Label("Descrição");
        labeldescricao.setFont(new Font(16));
        labeldescricao.setPrefSize(100, 35);
        labeldescricao.setLayoutX(5);
        labeldescricao.setLayoutY(280);

        textFielddescricao = new TextField();
        textFielddescricao.setPromptText("Descrição:");
        textFielddescricao.setPrefSize(300, 20);
        textFielddescricao.setLayoutX(5);
        textFielddescricao.setLayoutY(308);

        labelvalor = new Label("Valor");
        labelvalor.setFont(new Font(16));
        labelvalor.setPrefSize(80, 35);
        labelvalor.setLayoutX(320);
        labelvalor.setLayoutY(280);

        textFieldvalor = new TextField();
        textFieldvalor.setPromptText("Valor:");
        textFieldvalor.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        textFieldvalor.setLayoutX(320);
        textFieldvalor.setLayoutY(308);

        buttonNovo = new Button("Novo");
        buttonNovo.setPrefSize(60, 10);
        buttonNovo.setLayoutX(580);
        buttonNovo.setLayoutY(525);

        buttonSalvar = new Button("Salvar");
        buttonSalvar.setPrefSize(60, 10);
        buttonSalvar.setLayoutX(645);
        buttonSalvar.setLayoutY(525);

        buttonSalvar.setOnAction(e -> {

            String message = "";
            ObservableList<String> movies;
            movies = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

            for (String m : movies) {
                message += m + "\n";
            }
            System.out.println(message);

            String nome = tableColuna1.getText();
            String descricao = textFielddescricao.getText();
            String valor = textFieldvalor.getText();
            String diasaulas = tableColuna4.getText();
            String tiposaulas = tableColuna4.getText();

            agenda = agendadao.insert(nome, descricao, valor, diasaulas, tiposaulas);

            Main.fazerAgendamento(agenda);

        });

        choiceBox0 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox0.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox0.setLayoutX(580);
        choiceBox0.setLayoutY(310);
        choiceBox0.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox0.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox0.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox0.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox0.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox0.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox0.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox0.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox1 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox1.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox1.setLayoutX(580);
        choiceBox1.setLayoutY(340);
        choiceBox1.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox1.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox1.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox1.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox1.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox1.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox1.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox1.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox2 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox2.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox2.setLayoutX(650);
        choiceBox2.setLayoutY(310);
        choiceBox2.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox2.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox2.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox2.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox2.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox2.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox2.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox2.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox3 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox3.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox3.setLayoutX(650);
        choiceBox3.setLayoutY(340);
        choiceBox3.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox3.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox3.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox3.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox3.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox3.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox3.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox3.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox4 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox4.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox4.setLayoutX(580);
        choiceBox4.setLayoutY(370);
        choiceBox4.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox4.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox4.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox4.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox4.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox4.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox4.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox4.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox5 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox5.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox5.setLayoutX(650);
        choiceBox5.setLayoutY(370);
        choiceBox5.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox5.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox5.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox5.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox5.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox5.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox5.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox5.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox6 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox6.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox6.setLayoutX(580);
        choiceBox6.setLayoutY(400);
        choiceBox6.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox6.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox6.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox6.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox6.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox6.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox6.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox6.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox7 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox7.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox7.setLayoutX(650);
        choiceBox7.setLayoutY(400);
        choiceBox7.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox7.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox7.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox7.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox7.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox7.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox7.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox7.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox8 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox8.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox8.setLayoutX(580);
        choiceBox8.setLayoutY(430);
        choiceBox8.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox8.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox8.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox8.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox8.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox8.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox8.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox8.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox9 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox9.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox9.setLayoutX(650);
        choiceBox9.setLayoutY(430);
        choiceBox9.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox9.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox9.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox9.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox9.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox9.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox9.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox9.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox10 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox10.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox10.setLayoutX(580);
        choiceBox10.setLayoutY(460);
        choiceBox10.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox10.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox10.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox10.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox10.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox10.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox10.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox10.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox11 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox11.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox11.setLayoutX(650);
        choiceBox11.setLayoutY(460);
        choiceBox11.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox11.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox11.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox11.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox11.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox11.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox11.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox11.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox12 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox12.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox12.setLayoutX(580);
        choiceBox12.setLayoutY(490);
        choiceBox12.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox12.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox12.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox12.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox12.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox12.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox12.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox12.setValue("06:00");

        choiceBox13 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        choiceBox13.setDisable(true);
        choiceBox13.setLayoutX(650);
        choiceBox13.setLayoutY(490);
        // choiceBox13.setPrefSize(60,5);
        choiceBox13.getItems().add("06:00");
        choiceBox13.getItems().add("06:30");
        choiceBox13.getItems().add("07:00");
        choiceBox13.getItems().add("07:30");
        choiceBox13.getItems().add("08:00");
        choiceBox13.getItems().add("08:30");
        choiceBox13.getItems().add("09:00");
        choiceBox13.setValue("06:00");

        listView = new ListView<>();
        // listView.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        // root.setLeftAnchor(listView, 10.0);
        listView.setLayoutX(440);
        listView.setLayoutY(310);
        listView.setMaxSize(130, 200);
        listView.getItems().addAll("Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sabado");
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {

            if (table != null) {
                ObservableList<Agenda> agenda = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
                // table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                System.out.println(agenda);
            }
        });

        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(Event -> {

            listView.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {

                String message = "";
                ObservableList<String> movies;
                movies = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

                for (String m : movies) {
                    message += m;
                }

                if (message.equals("Domingo")) {
                    choiceBox0.setDisable(false);
                    choiceBox2.setDisable(false);

                } else {
                    choiceBox0.setDisable(true);
                    choiceBox2.setDisable(true);

                }

                if (message.equals("Segunda")) {
                    choiceBox1.setDisable(false);
                    choiceBox3.setDisable(false);

                } else {
                    choiceBox1.setDisable(true);
                    choiceBox3.setDisable(true);
                }

                if (message.equals("Terça")) {
                    choiceBox4.setDisable(false);
                    choiceBox5.setDisable(false);

                } else {
                    choiceBox4.setDisable(true);
                    choiceBox5.setDisable(true);
                }

                if (message.equals("Quarta")) {
                    choiceBox6.setDisable(false);
                    choiceBox7.setDisable(false);

                } else {
                    choiceBox6.setDisable(true);
                    choiceBox7.setDisable(true);
                }

                if (message.equals("Quinta")) {
                    choiceBox8.setDisable(false);
                    choiceBox9.setDisable(false);

                } else {
                    choiceBox8.setDisable(true);
                    choiceBox9.setDisable(true);
                }

                if (message.equals("Sexta")) {
                    choiceBox10.setDisable(false);
                    choiceBox11.setDisable(false);

                } else {
                    choiceBox10.setDisable(true);
                    choiceBox11.setDisable(true);
                }

                if (message.equals("Sabado")) {
                    choiceBox12.setDisable(false);
                    choiceBox13.setDisable(false);

                } else {
                    choiceBox12.setDisable(true);
                    choiceBox13.setDisable(true);
                }

            });

        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, choiceBox0, choiceBox1, choiceBox2, choiceBox3, choiceBox4, choiceBox5,
                choiceBox6, choiceBox7, choiceBox8, choiceBox9, choiceBox10, choiceBox11, choiceBox12, choiceBox13,
                labeldescricao, textFielddescricao, labelvalor, textFieldvalor, labelreferencia, buttonNovo,
                buttonSalvar);

        // root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #006400");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 730, 550);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("view/application.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);

    }

    /*
     * 
     * public void buttonClicked() { ObservableList<String> movies; String
     * message = ""; movies = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
     * 
     * for (String m : movies) { message += m + "\n"; }
     * System.out.println("Numero 1" + message); //
     * JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
     * 
     * }
     * 
     */
```

Classe Agenda

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import model.DAO.AgendaDAO;

public class Agenda {

    private SimpleIntegerProperty matricula;
    private SimpleStringProperty nome;
    private SimpleStringProperty valor;
    private SimpleStringProperty descricao;
    private SimpleStringProperty diasaulas;
    private SimpleStringProperty tiposaulas;

    public int getMatricula() {

        return matricula.get();
    }

    public void setMatricula(int matricula1) {
        matricula.set(matricula1);
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome.get();
    }

    public void setNome(String nome1) {
        nome.set(nome1);
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor.get();
    }

    public void setValor(String valor1) {
        valor.set(valor1);
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao.get();
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao1) {
        descricao.set(descricao1);
    }

    public String getDiasaulas() {
        return diasaulas.get();
    }

    public void setDiasaulas(String diasaulas1) {
        diasaulas.set(diasaulas1);
    }

    public String getTiposaulas() {
        return tiposaulas.get();
    }

    public void setTiposaulas(String tiposaulas1) {
        tiposaulas.set(tiposaulas1);
    }

    // public Agenda() {
    // this.nome = "";
    // this.valor1 = "";
    // this.descricao = "";
    // this.diasaulas = "";
    // this.tiposaulas = "";
    // }

    public Agenda(String matricula1, String nome1, String valor1, String descricao1, String diasaulas1,
            String tiposaulas1) {

        this.nome = new SimpleStringProperty(nome1);
        this.valor = new SimpleStringProperty(valor1);
        this.descricao = new SimpleStringProperty(descricao1);
        this.diasaulas = new SimpleStringProperty(diasaulas1);
        this.tiposaulas = new SimpleStringProperty(tiposaulas1);
    }

    public Agenda() {
        super();
    }

    public ObservableList<Agenda> atualizarTabela() {

        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(AgendaDAO.select());

    }

}``
```

Classe AgendaDAO

```
package model.DAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import model.Aluno;
import view.TelaAgenda;
import model.Agenda;

public class AgendaDAO {

    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/personalTuxaua;create=true;user=personal;password=1234";
    private static String tableName = "aluno";
    // jdbc Connection
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    public static void createConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            // Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        } catch (Exception except) {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Agenda insert(String nome, String descricao, String valor, String diasaulas, String tiposaulas) {
        createConnection();

        Agenda tabela = null;
        try {

            PreparedStatement user = conn
                    .prepareStatement("insert into aluno(nome,descricao,valor,diasaulas,tiposaulas)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            user.setString(1, nome);
            user.setString(2, descricao);
            user.setString(3, valor);
            user.setString(4, diasaulas);
            user.setString(5, tiposaulas);
            user.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seu cadastro foi concluido com sucesso");

        } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }

        // shutdown(); Desliga conexï¿½o com o banco
        // tabela = new Agenda(nome, descricao, valor, diasaulas, tiposaulas);
        return tabela;

    }

    public static List<Agenda> select() {

        createConnection();
        List<Agenda> agendas = new LinkedList<Agenda>();

        try {

            String sql = "select * from agenda";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            // stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // stmt.setString(1, nome+"%%");

            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (results.next()) {
                Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
                agenda.setMatricula(results.getInt(1));
                agenda.setNome(results.getString(2));
                agenda.setDescricao(results.getString(3));
                agenda.setValor(results.getString(4));
                agenda.setDiasaulas(results.getString(5));
                agenda.setTiposaulas(results.getString(6));

                agendas.add(agenda);

            }
            results.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(sqlExcept.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(agendas);

        return agendas;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Willian, uma dica, o campo que você usou para descrever a duvida é para o titulo, o campo logo abaixo, onde está o código é que é o campo adequado para descrever com detalhes a sua duvida. Arrumei a questão mas fica essa dica para perguntas posteriores, ah, aproveite e da uma olhada no **[tour]** para ver como funciona o site ;)

Comment: @William  O que não está dando certo especificamente?